# Android smack unable to get vcard for muc and loadvcard using muc id

Tags: android, smack, vcf-vcard, avatar, multiuserchat

I am using smack version 4.1.8 and server side I am using ejjabberd:

```
 VCard vcard = new VCard();
 vcard =  VCardManager.getInstanceFor(XMPPService.getMundioXmppConfig().getXmpptcpConnection()).loadVCard();
```

The above lines are giving vcard information for the login account , but I want to get vcard for particular jid.

and for that I tried:

```
vcard =  VCardManager.getInstanceFor(XMPPService.getMundioXmppConfig().getXmpptcpConnection()).loadVCard("testgroup@conference.localhost.com);
```

but it's not giving us the vcard.

Answer (score 0):

For getting MUC vcard

```
<iq to='test@conference.localhost' id='get1' type='get'> <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/> </iq>
```

Then, server will reply this:

```
<iq from="test@conference.localhost" type="result" to="user@localhost/r" id="get1"> <vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"> <PHOTO> <TYPE>image/png</TYPE> <BINVAL> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA`</BINVAL> </PHOTO> </vCard> </iq>`
```

[For more information about MUC vcard check this URL](https://docs.ejabberd.im/tutorials/muc-vcard/)

Comment: Hi Rakesh kalashetti  thanks for your answer , But i found that smack 4.1.8 which i am using is blocking the setTo function. So i modified the library and then it works. If any one using smack 4.1.8 if you want this functionality please go change there. vcard.setTo(fulljabberid). By default they are setting to null.